# jQuery UI Date Picker in AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a PHP script to generate some HTML that includes javascript (DatePicker from jQuery UI).

The PHP script is called from a main page using jQuery/AJAX.  All of my HTML renders without issue but I get a console error that says:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

I'm clearly doing something wrong but not much of a Javascript expert.  The code works fine if I call the new-fields.php directly but breaks when I get it via jQuery.  Appreciate any help!

Main.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('input[name="location"]').click(function(){
    var data = {location : jQuery(this).val(), department : $('input[name="department"]:checked').val()};
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/new-fields.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(result){
            jQuery('#div-custom').html(result).show();                
            $("#div-custom").find("script").each(function() {
                eval($(this).text());
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

New-fields.php:

```
    $picker =  '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <script>
                  $(function() {
                    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
                      numberOfMonths: 3,
                      showButtonPanel: true
                    });
                  });
                  </script>
                <script>
                  $(function() {
                    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
                      numberOfMonths: 3,
                      showButtonPanel: true
                    });
                  });
                  </script>

                  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
                  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>';

    echo $picker;
```

Comment: I'm not clear on how Main.html and New-fields.php fit together. Which one produces the error? Also (assuming that's your whole code) it's pointless to store your HTML string in a PHP variable like that and then echo it to the browser. Instead end your PHP tag with `?>` and then output your HTML directly.

Comment: Just a guess but since you are including query ui just before you call datepicker.. maybe it is calling the function before the library has finished loading and therefore it is not available to be run yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because in your main doc you use `jQuery`, I assume for no conflict purposes, in the `success` handler you use both `jQuery` and `$` and finally in the `ajax` response you use again the `$` notation.

My approach would be to move the javascript out of the `ajax` response.
Load all the `.js` files into your main document, take out all `<script>` references from the response and lose the `eval`.

Change the `ajax` `success` handler like this

```
success: function(result){
        jQuery('#div-custom').html(result).show();                
        jQuery("#div-custom").find("#datepicker1,#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
                  numberOfMonths: 3,
                  showButtonPanel: true
        });
}
```

and your `php` file should be just:

```
$picker =  '<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>';

echo $picker;
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply!  That makes a lot of sense.  I made those changes but now the console outputs Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).find(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: see the order you include `jquery` and `jquery-ui` you might be loading `jquery` after `jquery-ui`, or might be loading `jquery` twice

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!!